# React Native Navigation Test sample

Tags: react-native

So, I have been playing around with navigation in React Native and wanted to test something out with it. So I have generally been working with a stack navigation and have built it and works just fine. What I was testing around with was using navigate like I would in react.js and be able to just use that to move between components.

App.tsx

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Main from "./screens/main";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";


export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {/*<NavigationContainer>*/}
        <Main />
      {/*</NavigationContainer>*/}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Main.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { Button, View, Text } from "react-native";
import Home from "./home";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";


const App : FC = () => {
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    return(
        <View>
            <Text>This is just a holding screen</Text>
            <Button title="Home" onPress={()=> navigation.navigate(Home)}/>
        </View>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Home.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text} from "react-native";
import Main from "./main"

export default function App(){
    return(
        <View>
            <Text>
                Test this
            </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Not sure if this is even possible or just best to use the stack navigation? To me this is more similar to native development where I am on one screen and just call the screen that I want to move to.

I also was looking at the docs for this here.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#navigate

Answer (score 0):

React Navigation requires defining and registering all your navigation routes before navigating to them.

A simple example of stack navigation with multiple screens:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Profile"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Profile')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function ProfileScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Notifications"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Notifications')}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function NotificationsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button
        title="Go to Settings"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')}
      />
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Button title="Go back" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />
    </View>
  );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Notifications" component={NotificationsScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

In-depth docs - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#api-definition

Working Demo - https://snack.expo.dev/@emmbyiringiro/d7224b

Comment: ok, so no matter what I need that stack navigator and the screens defined in it. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah. It's a requirement.

Comment: Thank you. Was wondering about that.